# API Memory: Heap or Stack? (C++)

Tags: c++, api, memory-management, libraries

Context: I'm making a simple library. In it, I'm returning one of the classes I've created, which I could, a) declare on the stack and expect the user to copy to the heap if it needs to be on the heap, or, b) declare on the heap and expect the user to `delete` the object when they're done with it.

**Which of these methods is a best practice, and if there isn't a clear winner, which should be used where?** I'm thinking I'll create a `.dll` (`.so`, etc), but would the answer change if I were creating a different type of binary? What would happen if a user copied the headers and sources into their project and built the entire library each time they build their project. What would change?

Side note: I suppose a third option would be to allow a parameter to signify whether or not an object returned by a function is on the stack. This seems really convoluted, though, and I've never seen a library/API do that. A fourth option would be to allow a pointer to an already-existing object, which is then filled with new data. This way allows for the user to specify which sort of object they'd like, but it, again, seems rather convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

Always prefer automatic memory management. Only use dynamic memory management if you need dynamic lifetime. If your function's purpose is to return a T, there is no need for dynamic lifetime here.

If you do need dynamic lifetime, then do not ever deal with raw pointers to objects that you need to delete- always use smart pointers.

Also,

> expect the user to copy to the heap if it needs to be on the heap

You mean *move* to the heap, right?

Comment: I _do_ mean move! Does automatic memory management mean smart pointers?

Comment: @Jack: Er, no. I should have said "Automatic storage duration". And "dynamic storage duration".

Comment: I've never heard of those terms and my searchs for them don't return anything I can relate to the problem at hand (which I've pretty much finished, but I'd like to know how to do this sort of thing correctly).